# JavaScript AJAX call a PHP that returns XML

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to to do an AJAX call from javascript to a PHP File, that will update a database, then return to the original java script function XML data.  I think the disconnect i am having is getting the php to output correctly to be read as XML in the function.  Please see the code i have below.
---EDIT--- Simpler code to find heart of issue.

--ANSWERED-- The PHP File has to have the header set as XML.

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

Java Script:

```
function AddNewUser(){
document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML="<span>Started...</span>";
aj_test=new XMLHttpRequest();
aj_test.open("POST","test.php",true);
aj_test.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
alert("pre");
aj_test.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (aj_test.readyState==4 && aj_test.status==200)
    {
        XMLReturn=aj_test.responseXML;
        alert(XMLReturn.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }

}
aj_test.send("");
```

}

PHP:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: You need to escape your URL parameters.

Comment: It looks like you have all the ingredients you need, so I suspect you're right and that the issue concerns how you're passing the XML back to the javascript client.  How are you echoing or emitting $XMLData, and what data does the javascript client actually receive?

Comment: Updated code, with simple static string for testing.  if u use responseText; then i get all the information as formated correctly as XML, but i need it passed as XML so i can find specific data.

Comment: Glad you got to the heart of the matter.  I believe I've found my way through the same problem once or twice before!

Answer (score 1):

--ANSWERED-- The PHP File has to have the header set as XML.

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```